# Frontend promise always pending backend node js call

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, es6-promise

I have my react frontend which is very basic right now as i just want to retrieve some data from my backend api written in node js which calls and external api
the data is fetched properly to the backend as I have tested it by printing the data. The issue is that my promise on the frontend is never resolved meaning the data is never fetched

frontend code so far:

```
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
 
  const getDataPromise = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:8800/api/auth/data"
    );
    console.log("ACTIVITY RESPONSE = ", response);
    //return data;
  };

  const getActivities = async () => {

    const promiseData = await getDataPromise()
    // NEVER RESOLVES
    console.log("Promise data = ", promiseData);
    //getDataPromise().then((res) => console.log("RES = ", res));
    //}
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
     
      <button onClick={getActivities}>Get All Data</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

backend section of code with api link replaced with text:

```
 async function getDataPromise() {
  const link = `externalAPI`;
  

  const response = await axios.get(link);
  console.log("Response = ", response.data[0]);
  return response.data[0];
}

router.get("/data", async (req, res) => {

  const data = await getDataPromise();
  console.log("data = ", data);
  return data;
});
```

Does anyone see my issue why my frontend promise when the getData button is clicked never resolves so the promiseData value is eventually printed

Comment: You'll want to send a response from your backend, not return the data. e.g. `res.json(data)` instead of `return data`

Comment: You should send a response in your backend.

Comment: @DennisMartinez thank you I am new to full stack development so how does this work over what I was doing previously?

Comment: @program.exe You should respond to requests in your backend. In `/data` route write `res.status(200).json(data)` instead of returning a data.

Comment: What backend framework are you using, what is `router`?

Answer (score -1):

It's on backend side

```
router.get("/data", async (req, res) => {

  const data = await getDataPromise();
  console.log("data = ", data);
  return data;
});
```

Try to replace
`return data`
with
`res(data)`

Comment: Did you mean `res.send(data)`